# How to provide defaults value for partial parameters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templating

I need to render a shared partial which can receive a few parameters from several views, but I don't want to pass all parameters everytime. If I call the template without all parameters, I get an error.

Is there a way to define default values for parameters, only if they haven't been defined when calling `render 'name_of_partial`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<% my_param ||= 'default value' %>
```

A partial that contains this can be rendered with or without providing `my_param`.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the docs, and some head scratching, I was able to define default values for parameters not passed to the template.

```
# in views/shared/template.html.erb
<% my_param = 'default_value' unless binding.local_variable_defined?(:my_param) %>
# Now you can call the partial with or without setting `my_param`

# Now you can call the partial without parameters...
<%= render 'shared/my_template' %>
# ...or with parameters
<%= render 'shared/my_template', my_param: 'non-default value' %>
```

Tested with Ruby 2.3.1 and upwards.

This handles passing `false` or `nil` as a parameter without it being overwritten by the default value.  The accepted answer does not handle this case.

Comment: Why do you need all this? Just using `<% my_param ||= 'default value' %>` works.

Comment: @DannyB Damnit, you're absolutely right! Why didn't I think of that? If you want to submit an answer instead of a comment I'll be happy to vote it up :-)

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

With Rails >=7.1 you can define strict locals with a magic comment:

`<%# locals: (my_param: "default value") -%>`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#strict-locals